# How to knew if I have a lexical error in grammar file .g4 in antlr4?

Tags: antlr4

I am using antlr 4 with java ... I implement my own listener and save the errors produce by antlr4 in list ... and I build my ast ... My question is: 
there are any method to knew if I have an error in my listener then stop building ast ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing your own **default error strategy** and simply return whatever error is caught and break from its current action to the method where you output your ast.

See these links for help:

[Default error strategy](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.html)

[The antlr guy's guide](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Error+reporting+and+recovery) 
(my recommended reading for this issue)

Once you implement your own default error strategy you could simply have a method within in keep a list of all the errors and return those, or use a not null check to see whether to continue onto the next step of your parsing.

Hope this helps in anyway and good luck on your project.